# Append button to MCE toolbar instead of replace (Plugins)

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to add a plugin to tinyMCE (the textcolor plugin) and I've managed to get it working. However, there's a small issue with the toolbar that I can't seem to figure out. Namely, how do I *add* the buttons from the plugin instead of *replacing* the existing toolbar?

My Init Code

```
//TinyMCE Test
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.editor',
    branding: false,
    height : "200",
    plugins: "textcolor",
    toolbar: "forecolor backcolor"
});
```

I can see that it's this line `toolbar: "forecolor backcolor"` that's doing it, but I can't figure out how to append. I've looked at the [docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/textcolor/) but still can't figure it out.

Before Plugin
[image]

After Plugin
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE does not have way to append to the default toolbar.  Once you define the toolbar yourself you need to define 100% of what you want to show on the toolbar.

As of TinyMCE 4.7.13 the default toolbar is:

```
var defaultToolbar = 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic |' + 
                     'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |' + 
                     'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image';
```

***Note:*** *This data can be found in the `theme.js` file.*

Comment: Ah, I feared that'd be the case. Thanks for the info!